# Is there some Riemannian manifold's version of Whitney theorem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given any Riemannian or [Semi-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$, does there exist a Eucildean space $(E,g^\prime)$ of enough high dimension with metric $g^\prime=diag\{-1,-1,...,+1,+1,...\}$ with any n copies of "$-1$" and m "$+1$" such that $(M,g)$ is embedded in $(E,g^\prime)$ and $g$ is the induced metric of $g^\prime$ ?

Comment: For Riemannian manifolds this is the Nash embedding theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, have a look at Robert Greene's book *Isometric Embeddings of Riemannian and Pseudo Riemannian Manifolds,*  Volume 97 of Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society
Memoirs, 1970.

Answer (score 1):

For the Lorentzian case see http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4439.
In this article the authors give conditions for the existence of the imbedding.